# Child component function not called from parent in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I am using reactjs to build a game. I have a parent component and I am trying to call a method in child component using ref but its not working. Can someone help why? (ignore case in below ex.)

```
function parent() {
    childRef = useRef()

    ...
    const someFunc = () => {
        childRef.current.childFunc()
    }
    ...
    return <Child ref={childRef} />
}

function Child() {
    ...
    const childFunc = () => {
        ... code ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Error: Cannot read property 'childFunc' of undefined

Comment: please check [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296075/method-calling-in-reactjs) hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

see [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)

I believe it would be something along these lines:

```
function parent() {
    childRef = useRef()

    ...
    const someFunc = () => {
        childRef.current.childFunc()
    }
    ...
    return <Child ref={childRef} />
}

function Child(props, ref) {
    ...
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      childFunc: () => {
        ... code ...
      }
    }));
    ...
}

Child = forwardRef(Child);
```